# How to pass value/variable from one function to another in django - views

Tags: python, django, django-views

Not able to pass a variable from one function to another.

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def UserList(request):
    loc = User.objects.all()
    latest_id = User.objects.latest('userid').userid  #want to pass this variable into DetailList function
    serializer = UserSerializer(loc, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)

@api_view(['GET'])
def DetailList(request):
    loc = Detail.objects.all()
    serializer = DetailSerializer(loc, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

and finaly want to use that userid variable to add the data into Detail table.

```
class UserAPIView(APIView):
    def post(self, request ):
        userid = request.data.get('userid')
        name = request.data.get('name')
        age = request.data.get('age')
        gender = request.data.get('gender')
        address = request.data.get('address')
        phone = request.data.get('phone')
        user_serializer = UserSerializer(data={"name": name, "age": age, "gender": gender})
        detail_serializer = DetailSerializer(data={"userid": userid,"address": address, "phone": phone})
        if user_serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
            user_serializer.save()
        if detail_serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
            detail_serializer.save()
        return Response({'status': 'Success'})
```

not able to pass variable data through declaring global , as getting error Nulltype is not callable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Functions itself are stateles, in a meaning that each function have it's own context and context isn't shared between them. The only "bridge" you have, else then keep some data on frontend side, is to use DB or [Django sessions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/http/sessions/) as mentioned in previous answer. For the last one here's an example:

```py
@api_view(['GET'])
def UserList(request):
    loc = User.objects.all()
    latest_id = User.objects.latest('userid').userid  #want to pass this variable into DetailList function
    request.session['latest_id'] = latest_id  # here you set session var
    serializer = UserSerializer(loc, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)

@api_view(['GET'])
def DetailList(request):
    loc = Detail.objects.all()
    latest_id = request.session.get('latest_id')  # here you get session var
    serializer = DetailSerializer(loc, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to pass data from one view to another view, but I have an idea about the session, you can do same thing with session

#set session from view

```
request.session['session_name'] = session_value
```

#get session from another view

```
session_var = request.session.get('session_name')
```